# PHP Highlight searched words in results with str_ireplace in $result = $db->query($query);

Tags: php

I've read previous posts but I didn't find solution.
In row 
       $result = $db->query($query);
I'd like to have text of query 'keyword' highlighted

I've try str_ireplace without success.

```
  $aKeyword = explode(" ", $_POST['keyword']);
  $query ="SELECT * FROM annullamenti WHERE testo OR title OR citta like '%" . $aKeyword[0] . "%'";

 for($i = 1; $i < count($aKeyword); $i++) {
    if(!empty($aKeyword[$i])) {
        $query .= " AND testo like '%" . $aKeyword[$i] . "%'";
    }
  }

   $result = $db->query($query);


 if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $row_count=0;
    While($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {   
        $row_count++;
```

Comment: The given code is incomplete. it has unmatched brackets

Comment: The code in your question is only sort of related, you may be better off showing an example of the text you retrieve and how the highlighting would affect it.  You should also show any code you have which does this part, at the moment you show how you retrieve the text.

Comment: I's only a part of the code. The row for  highlight text with tags <mark> </mark> $result = $db->query($query);

Comment: `str_replace($searchTerm, "<mark>{$seatchTerm}</mark>", $value)`?

Comment: I try to change $result = $db->query($query); with $result = $db->query("<mark>$query</mark>"); without success

Comment: does that sql query return the results you would expect? I ask because of the strict conditions it will apply when using `and testo like %WORD%` etc

Comment: the return is ok, I need search terms highlighted

Comment: _“I've try str_ireplace without success.”_ - please _show us_ what you tried in such cases; describe what you did expect to happen, and what happened instead.

Answer (score 0):

One method you might employ would be `preg_replace` where you generate the necessary arrays of patterns and replacements as you iterate through all the supplied keywords. The following uses that approach and combines it with a dynamically generated sql query that is executed as a `prepared statement` - tip of the hat here to @Nigel-Ren for the tip regarding the `splat` operator!

Not knowing what data is held within the `annullamenti` table it is hard to know if the strict query will return the values necessary or not but using `OR` to join alternative clauses worked in tests.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>search and replace - highlight words</title>
        <style>
            span{color:red;background:yellow}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method='post'>
            <input type='text' name='keyword' />
            <input type='submit' />
        </form>
        <?php
            if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){

                /* include database connection */
                require 'db.php';

                /* 
                    join the alternative conditions using this phrase.
                    Using `AND` will make the query very strict as ALL conditions must be true ( as is the case in the original sql )
                    whereas using `OR` will make it more relaxed... for testing I opted for `OR`
                */
                $joiner=' and ';

                /* types placeholder */
                $types='';

                /* params placeholder array */
                $params=array();

                /* clauses */
                $clauses=array();

                /* regExp patterns array */
                $pttns=array();

                /* replacement phrases - highlighted words */
                $replace=array();


                if( !empty( $_POST['keyword'] ) ){

                    $keywords=explode( ' ', $_POST['keyword'] );
                    $word=$keywords[0];


                    $sql='select * from `annullamenti`';

                    /* add clauses for each of the initial conditions */
                    $clauses[]='( testo like ? or title like ? or citta like ? )';
                    $params[]="%{$word}%";
                    $params[]="%{$word}%";
                    $params[]="%{$word}%";

                    /* add first pattern */
                    $pttns[]=sprintf( '/%s/', $word );

                    /* add first replacement */
                    $replace[]=sprintf( '<span>%s</span>', $word );


                    /* process any other keywords given */
                    for( $i=1; $i < count( $keywords ); $i++ ){
                        $word=$keywords[ $i ];

                        $clauses[]='testo like ?';
                        $params[]="%{$word}%";

                        $pttns[]=sprintf( '/%s/', $word );
                        $replace[]=sprintf( '<span>%s</span>', $word );
                    }

                    /* determine the `types` string to match the number of parameters */
                    $types=str_repeat('s', count( $params ) );

                    /* generate the final dynamic SQL statement */
                    $sql=sprintf('%s where %s', $sql, implode( $joiner , $clauses ) );


                    /* create the prepared statement */
                    $stmt=$db->prepare( $sql );

                    if( $stmt ){
                        /*
                            bind the types and the params to the statement using the `splat` operator (...)
                        */
                        $stmt->bind_param( $types, ...$params );

                        /* run the query */
                        $result = $stmt->execute();
                        if( $result ){

                            $result=$stmt->get_result();
                            while( $rs=$result->fetch_object() ){

                                /* create the output string that is to have keywords highlighted */
                                $data = sprintf( "testo:%s, title:%s, citta:%s\n", $rs->testo, $rs->title, $rs->citta );

                                /* perform the regExp search and replace to create the highlighted string */
                                $modified = preg_replace( $pttns, $replace, $data );

                                /* output the highlighted string */
                                echo nl2br( $modified );
                            }
                        }else{
                            echo 'No results';
                        }
                    } else {
                        echo 'Bad foo - statement failed!';
                    }
                }
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I so I must change all... why I can't replace row $result = $db->query($query); with $result = $db->query("<mark>$query</mark>");

Comment: because that is not how it would work...  `$db->query()` would expect valid sql - including `<mark>$query</mark>` is not valid at all

Comment: Send me what code and why? Have you tried the above or to use this in your own implementation? `$db->query("<mark>$query</mark>");` will not work, ever!

Comment: I've try the code above but always only blank page output. I use php 5.3.9 but try also php 7.3.5 in http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/ Thank you